# Java paintComponents is not being called

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw some things on the `JPanel` but it seems I have encountered an issue with the `paint` and `paintComponent` methods. Might have something to do with double buffering but I am not sure. `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method is not being called for some reason, any idea why?

here's my code:

```
   @Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    System.out.println("paintComponents!");

    snakeHead.DrawSphere(g);

    if(foodShoulBeRedrawn){
        foodShoulBeRedrawn = false;
        spawnFood();
    }

    if(shouldSpawnBodyPart){
        shouldSpawnBodyPart = false;
        snake.get(snake.size() - 1).DrawSphere(g);

    }

    //spawnSnake();
    paintCalled = true;

    repaint();
}

/*
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    snakeHead.DrawSphere(g);

    if(foodShoulBeRedrawn){
        foodShoulBeRedrawn = false;
        spawnFood();
    }

    if(shouldSpawnBodyPart){
        shouldSpawnBodyPart = false;
        snake.get(snake.size() - 1).DrawSphere(g);

    }

    //spawnSnake();
    paintCalled = true;

    repaint();
}
*/
```

Comment: *"paint-Components()"* No. it is **singular** - `paintComponent(Graphics)` ..

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I just didn't bother, you know what these functions are, I anyway posted the entire code.

Comment: *"posted the entire code"* 1) **Don't** dump your entire code. If you could not be bothered making an MCVE, many could not be bothered trying to help. 2) It was not the entire code in any case. No `main(String[])` method to launch it, no imports, no definition for classes like `Sphere3D` .. *"I just didn't bother"* ..and it shows.

Comment: Calling repaint() will cause the component to invoke its paint methods, including paintComponent, so calling repaint from a paint method creates an infinite loop.  Do not call repaint from any paint method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overriding [`Container#paintComponents()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), which was inherited by your `JFrame`. Instead of extending `JFrame`, you need to extend [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) so you can override its `paintComponent()` and `getPreferredSize()`. Then you can `add()` the panel to a `JFrame`, like they show [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bswing%5D%20extends%20jpanel%20override%20paintComponent).

Comment: Did you intend for your second link to point to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics- ?

Comment: Cool, thanks! I did this one with the help of the JForm, so from what I understood it automatically adds everything, NetBeans itself. So yea, thank you! :)

Comment: @VGR: No, but what I had wasn't very clear. Thanks for saying something.  I was trying to steer the Emperor to `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

I think JFrame is not a JComponent so paintComponent method is never going to be called. 
You should put all your paint methods in a JPanel and include it in your JFrame.